# Collapsing Toolbar Layout Scroll even when there is no scrolling content in Nested Scroll View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am using Collapsing toolbar layout in my project in which I am using one `NestedScrollView` in which I have multiple Card Views in which the content is not static instead it changes in `onActivityResult`. I have set minimum height of `CollapsingToolbarLayout` as 100dp. So I have observed couple of issues in it:

1. On big phones the content scrolls up to minimum height 100dp leaving a large empty space at bottom which is not desired result. It should scroll up only when it is necessary. Necessary Condition is that when I get large text value in Text fields it should scroll otherwise not.
2. I have used [Natario Solution](https://github.com/natario1/ConstrainedScrollBehavior) in it which calculates minimum height of `CollapsingToolbarLayout` dynamically which works somehow but it vanish the scroll ability of `NestedScrollView` If I get large dynamic texts, which is not desired result.

My layout.xml file is:-

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/topBlock"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:minHeight="100dp">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapse_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"

                android:minHeight="100dp"

                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
                app:layout_scrollInterpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">


            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/camera"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/nestedScrollView"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="top|center_horizontal"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

       

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    ////My Scrolling Content(Contains many edit texts so its size may vary)
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have not done anything in MyActivity.kt file. Please help me out this. I have tried nearly all solutions in this community from last 15 days still no luck. Thanks!!

Edit: As Suggested I have updated the Question with `NestedScrollView` as direct child and posted Screenshot of Android Studio preview in which it is taking height which is crossing preview. It should take height according to the content.If I make `NestedScrollView` wrap_content then still it leaves empty space at bottom. In background I have Camera running so I have to make it match parent to make cover full height.[image]

Comment: One obvious thing that I can see is that your nested scroll view is not a direct child of your coordinator layout so have no effect on the collapsing toolbar. Also, your view hierarchy is wrong and has many other problems that can cause the issue.

Comment: I cannot imagine how this will run any smoothly on any android device. You should consider learning basic programming principles like Seperation of Concerns: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns. And Android specific principles like the one Activity multiple Fragments approach: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Design.

Comment: @MohammadOmidvar Yes Sure Thanks I will add nestedScrollView as direct child of CoordinatorLayout and check.

Comment: @RenéSpies Yes Thanks I will look at the link but I already have Single activity Application.I use SOC, RXJAVA databinding, MVVM Architecture, DI everything to reach Android Design Standards. I am just having issues in my xml, so I modified my xml to make it easy to run without any resource dependency or Fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no particular solution to your problem, but I highly suggest you to embrace **Motion Layout**. I'm developing an app with a 'collapsing toolbar' too, and I wanted to do a parallax effect, just like in Spotify. It got really difficult using Coordinator Layout and Collapsing Toolbar, besides the documentation about it are not very extensive so honestly I didn't know what I was doing.

I researched online for other ways to do it and finally I found out about this. Motion Layout lets you **tweek your animations** to the very little details. I know that thinking of changing your whole layout from CoordinatorLayout to MotionLayout seems like a lot of work but it isn't. And if anything it's rewarding given that Motion Layout extends from Constraint Layout and you can animate every view of your layout (if your parent is Motion Layout). Another pro-ML argument is that you have animation listeners: for example when a transition is done, a method is called automatically and this way you can chain animations if you need to, it's really fun.

1. Check out some of the **possible animations** that you can build with Motion Layout. These come with the layouts xml and the animation xml so you can learn from these (great official documentation btw):
   https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout/examples
2. This is the tutorial I used to imitate the behavior of the Collapsing Toolbar inside a Coordinator Layout:
   https://blog.stylingandroid.com/motionlayout-collapsing-toolbar-part-1/
   https://blog.stylingandroid.com/motionlayout-collapsing-toolbar-part-2/
   (I personally just went through part1 then continued on my own)

Comment: Thanks @Agustin Magne.  I also removed the collapsing toolbar layout as I was not having specific requirement. I ended up with simple nested scroll view with transparent background at top and some logic and got the desired effect. This motion layout is new for me I will definetly try it.

Comment: This doesn't really answer to the question directly. That's more like an another approach for another topic.

Comment: True! I just added this because OP was looking for an "up-to-date" answer :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no need for `ConstraintLayout` since you have the `CoordinatorLayout`. Also as mentioned by users in comments, `NestedScrollView` should be a direct child of `CoordinatorLayout` and not in the `ConstraintLayout`. In this way you designed, some behaviors might not work as expected and it's actually a wrong design.

I've made the changes and here is what you'd see in the preview:

[image]

**UPDATED layout:**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/topBlock"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:layout_scrollInterpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme"
                app:title="Your title" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:text="MyRandomText"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="42sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view"
                app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|center_horizontal" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

P.S: Please also remember that the `NestedScrollView` should have **only one child** as it's first child.

In this way which is the right way to do, you won't have to use kotlin-java codes to achieve scrolling or other behaviors, you'll be able to achieve the behaviors using flags and attributes like `layout_scrollFlags` and `exitUntilCollapsed` and the like.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but It still have empty space. I have updated the question with screenshot to make it clear.

Comment: @AfzalKhan Try to add `android:clipToPadding="false"` and  `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to your `NestedScrollView`. I'll update the answer

Comment: I used that but it is still scrolling up to minimum height of 100dp. It should only scroll when there is enough content in Nested Scroll view which is case of small phones. On big phones if all content is visible it shouldn't scroll.

Comment: It's probably because of  `android:minHeight="100dp"` in the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` I actually forgot to remove it. Please try the updated answer.

Comment: your code makes toolbar always pinned, no matter if content is enough to scroll